# Сервис выдает ошибку 1053

Tags: c#, service, служба

Пишу сервис на C# с использованием .NET Framework 4.6.1, сервис первое время запускался и работал нормально, после пары правок перестал запускаться и выдавал ошибку 1053. Откатил до той версии которая работала, ошибка 1053 осталась, сервис по прежнему не хочет запускаться. Пробовал проект заново создать, создав сам сервис по новой, вставив основной код, создал установщик по новой, но даже так 1053 ошибка. Основной рабочий код брал с [примера](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer). Не знаю может ли помочь код сервиса, но в любом случае вот он:

```
using FileSaverInterface;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Timers;

namespace FileSaverService
{
public partial class FileSaverService : ServiceBase
{
    public string EndDir;
    public string StartDir;

    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool SetServiceStatus(System.IntPtr handle, ref ServiceStatus serviceStatus);

    public FileSaverService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ServiceLogger = new EventLog();

        if (!EventLog.SourceExists("FileSaverServiceSource"))
        {
            EventLog.CreateEventSource("FileSaverServiceSource", "FileSaverServiceLog");
        }

        ServiceLogger.Source = "FileSaverServiceSource";
        ServiceLogger.Log = "FileSaverServiceLog";
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        // Update the service state to Start Pending.
        ServiceStatus serviceStatus = new ServiceStatus();
        serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_START_PENDING;
        serviceStatus.dwWaitHint = 100000;
        SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);

        ServiceLogger.WriteEntry("Service OnStarted");

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 180000; // 180 seconds
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimer);
        timer.Start();

        ServiceLogger.WriteEntry("Timer Sarted");

        // Update the service state to Running.
        serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_RUNNING;
        SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        // Update the service state to Stop Pending.
        ServiceStatus serviceStatus = new ServiceStatus();
        serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING;
        serviceStatus.dwWaitHint = 100000;
        SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);

        ServiceLogger.WriteEntry("Service OnStopped");

        // Update the service state to Stopped.
        serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_STOPPED;
        SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);
    }
    public void OnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        StartDir = mainWindow.StartDirectory;
        EndDir = mainWindow.EndDirectory;

        // TODO: Insert monitoring activities here.
        ServiceLogger.WriteEntry($"Start Directory: {EndDir}");
        ServiceLogger.WriteEntry($"End Directory: {EndDir}");

        ServiceLogger.WriteEntry("Main operations started");
        ServiceLogger.WriteEntry($"Checked if {EndDir} exists");

        if (!Directory.Exists(EndDir))
        {
            ServiceLogger.WriteEntry($"Folder {EndDir} don't exists. Try create.");
            DirectoryWork.DirectoryCreate(EndDir);
            ServiceLogger.WriteEntry($"Create {EndDir} ended.");
        }
        else
        {
            ServiceLogger.WriteEntry($"Directory {EndDir} exists");
            ServiceLogger.WriteEntry($"Try to clear {EndDir}");

            Directory.Delete(EndDir, true);
            DirectoryWork.DirectoryCreate(EndDir);

            ServiceLogger.WriteEntry($"Folder {EndDir} cleared");
        }

        if (!Directory.Exists(EndDir))
        {
            ServiceLogger.WriteEntry($"Folder {EndDir} don't exists. Try create.");
            DirectoryWork.DirectoryCreate(EndDir);
            ServiceLogger.WriteEntry($"Create {EndDir} ended.");
        }

        ServiceLogger.WriteEntry("Starting copy method");

        DirectoryWork.DirectoryCopy(StartDir, EndDir, true);

        ServiceLogger.WriteEntry("Copy method ended");
        ServiceLogger.WriteEntry("All operation ended");
    }

    public enum ServiceState
    {
        SERVICE_STOPPED = 0x00000001,
        SERVICE_START_PENDING = 0x00000002,
        SERVICE_STOP_PENDING = 0x00000003,
        SERVICE_RUNNING = 0x00000004,
        SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING = 0x00000005,
        SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING = 0x00000006,
        SERVICE_PAUSED = 0x00000007,
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct ServiceStatus
    {
        public int dwServiceType;
        public ServiceState dwCurrentState;
        public int dwControlsAccepted;
        public int dwWin32ExitCode;
        public int dwServiceSpecificExitCode;
        public int dwCheckPoint;
        public int dwWaitHint;
    };
}
}
```

Может у меня с системой проблемы? Тестировал на другом компьютере, всё тоже самое. Маюсь уже долго, эти сервисы ломаются при любой удобной возможности, каждый раз создавать совершенно новый сервис — нету сил.
Устанавливал сервис с помощью InstallUtil, удалял тоже.

Пошарился и нашёл в "Просмотр событий" ошибки связанные с запуском сервиса, вот что пишет:

```
Приложение: FileSaverService.exe
Версия платформы: v4.0.30319
Описание. Процесс был завершен из-за необработанного исключения.
Сведения об исключении: System.InvalidOperationException
в System.Windows.Input.InputManager..ctor()
в System.Windows.Input.InputManager.GetCurrentInputManagerImpl()
в System.Windows.Input.KeyboardNavigation..ctor()
в System.Windows.FrameworkElement+FrameworkServices..ctor()
в System.Windows.FrameworkElement.EnsureFrameworkServices()
в System.Windows.FrameworkElement..ctor()
в System.Windows.Controls.Control..ctor()
в System.Windows.Window..ctor()
в FileSaverInterface.MainWindow..ctor()
в FileSaverService.FileSaverService..ctor()
в FileSaverService.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

Буду надеется что это поможет решить проблему. На этом этапе я понял, что косяк всё-таки в коде, но пока что разобраться не могу. И да, в проекте так же присутствует интерфейс на WPF, который по идее и должен запускать службу, при нажатии кнопки. Думаю с этим может быть связанна проблема (хотя раньше сервис и запускался и останавливался через кнопки). Вот методы из интерфейса, которые взаимодействуют с сервисом:

```
        private void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        serviceController.ServiceName = "FileSaverServiceName";

        if (!Directory.Exists(StartDirectory) || StartDirectory.Length <= 3)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show($"Директория {StartDirectory} не найдена или указана неверно", "Ошибка");
            return;
        }

        if (!Directory.Exists(EndDirectory) || EndDirectory.Length <= 3)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show($"Директория {EndDirectory} не найдена или указана неверно", "Ошибка");
            return;
        }

        serviceController.Start();
        ServiceLogger.WriteEntry("Service Started from interface");
    }

    private void ButtonStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        serviceController.Stop();
        ServiceLogger.WriteEntry("Service Stopped from interface");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У сервиса по умолчанию не доступа к UI. Уберите из сервиса работу с окном:

```
MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
```

А настройки

```
StartDir = mainWindow.StartDirectory;
EndDir = mainWindow.EndDirectory;
```

перенесите в место, куда будет доступ и у сервиса и у оконного приложения. Например, в реестр.

В сервисе читайте значения из реестра, в окнонном приложении - пишите их в реестр + перезапускайте сервис.